# Why didn't installing Blender 2.82 delete 2.80?

Tags: installation

Installing version 2.82 did not automatically delete version 2.8. Is it standard for a new version of Blender to not delete the previous version in the installation process?

Comment: as thibsert you can have different versions of Blender, even different copies of the same version, it might help sometimes, because you could want to go back to a previous version, or you can launch a render on a copy and work on another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies with the OS and the method of installation (archive, repository, installer...).

It's totally fine to have two (or many more) different versions installed, that shouldn't cause any issue. Of course, feel free to manually uninstall the version you don't need anymore.